# Controlling user sessions

Tags: session, video-streaming

The client has a streaming server (unknown for us at this time) that is used for streaming H.264 streams from IP cameras. This is fine in their LAN.

Now they want to allow authorized users to watch the streams over the internet. But they have few requests for these internet users:

1. The users have to "login" to the application to watch the streams.
2. The user should have only one streaming session at a time.
3. The session has to be limited by some time on daily bases.

Our solution should have an independent application server for this, with database server etc... And our application should control the access to the streaming server

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, sounds like you only need to implement user session control using something like PHP. Require every user to have an account, then monitor the sessions they are accessing, including checking the time the session has been active :)

Comment: It's not easy as it seems. I need to control the session on different browsers. Restrict the access to the streaming server over which I have no control. I was thinking of re-streaming the stream and have control over it (stopping the stream after a while). The thing is that I have no experience with streaming (servers, players etc.). So I was looking for pointers about all this.

Comment: The session control is the easier part. The stream control is the thing I have a problem with.